# accessing progress bar via a secondary class

Tags: c#

I have two classes, `Form1.cs` and `secondclass.cs`, I'm trying to do something on `secondclass.cs` and send the progress to a progress bar on `Form1.cs` , this is my current code:

`Form1.cs`

```
namespace DifferentClasses
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            secondclass.updateBar(20);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.setBar(20);
        }

        public void setBar(int percentage)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value += percentage;
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(percentage));
        }
    }
}
```

`secondclass.cs`

```
namespace DifferentClasses
{
    class secondclass
    {
        public static void updateBar(int percentage)
        {
            var frm = new Form1();
            frm.setBar(percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

(this was a new project to test what I actually want in my main program)
as you see I have created 2 buttons, the first one runs the command via `secondclass.cs`
and the second one runs it directly from the same class. Funny enough both don't give errors
and both return the console line, however the first button doesn't actually change the progress bar and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You could try adding `this.progressBar1.Refresh();` after you set the value

Comment: Nope still nothing @Nunners :( Good try though, EDIT: I dont know if i'm doing it good either, pretty new to c# hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in updateBar you are creating a new Form1 and setting the percentage on that.
The simplest way to solve this is to pass a reference to the current form into updateBar like this:

```
public static void updateBar(int percentage,Form1 f)
{
    f.setBar(percentage);
}
```

and in the calling code do this:

```
secondclass.updateBar(20,this);
```

I'm guess the secondclass will end up running something which may take some time, so you may want to look at the async features in C#

Comment: This way I dont even need the setBar() function, I can also directly access the bar if I set it to public :D